# Posting a ByteArray to a WebService returning a bad request in android

Tags: java, android, web-services

I have a Webservice hosted  - 
When I send data through a client application in C# it is able to post successfully and response from the server - but my android application is returning 400 : Bad Request

a) I have made sure that the URL is correct
b) The app has appropriate permission
c) I have made sure that the byte[] which is being passed to the function is correct - as I reversed the process to check if it is able to form the file - which it does.

Following is the code in C# - (which is working)

```
public static string PostAudio(byte[] bytes, string orderid, string mobilenumber, string fileformat, string status){
    try
    {
        string _serviceaudiourl = "https://www.capricorn.cash/getway.svc/uploadaudio/?token={0}&orderid={1}&mobilenumber={2}&fileformat={3}&status={4}"; 
        string _servicetoken = "DD9BBF0C749261F3A3F5D9AE62CFE29E"; 
        string serviceUrl = string.Format(_serviceaudiourl, _servicetoken, orderid, mobilenumber, fileformat, status);

        string response = "";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Timeout = 120000;
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream requeststream = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requeststream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requeststream.Close();
        }


        using (HttpWebResponse webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
                sr.Close();
            }
            webResponse.Close();
        }
        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "Error:" + ex.Message;
    }
```

This is my Android function

```
public String PostAudio(byte[] bytes1, String orderid, String mobilenumber, String fileformat, String status) 
    {
        String serviceUrl;
        try
        {
            String _servicetoken = "DD9BBF0C749261F3A3F5D9AE62CFE29E"; 
            serviceUrl =  "https://www.capricorn.cash/getway.svc/uploadaudio/?token=" + _servicetoken + "&orderid=" + orderid + "&mobilenumber=" + mobilenumber + "&fileformat=" + fileformat +  "&status=" + status; 
            java.net.URL iurl = new java.net.URL(serviceUrl);

            HttpURLConnection req = (HttpURLConnection) iurl.openConnection();
            req.setDoInput(true);
            req.setDoOutput(true);  
            req.setRequestMethod("POST");
            req.setConnectTimeout(120000);    
            req.setUseCaches (false);     
            req.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(bytes1.length));

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (req.getOutputStream());                            
            wr.write(bytes1,0, bytes1.length);
            wr.flush ();
            wr.close ();

            InputStream is;
            int stat = req.getResponseCode();

            if (stat == 400){
                is = req.getErrorStream();
            }
            else{
                is = req.getInputStream();
            }

            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
              response.append(line);
              response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            return "IO Error:" + e.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return "Error:" + ex.toString();
        }
    }
```

..Can any please tell where exactly am I going wrong!?!

Comment: I just wanted to add on the above question is that the file size that I tried sending was 380 KB (the file format was mp3)

Comment: `but my android application is returning 400 :` ?? Do you mean: the webservice is returning 400 to my android application?

Comment: `string serviceUrl = string.Format(_serviceau.......`. Please tell what that string contains constructing it like that.

Comment: Yes..the webservice is returning 400 ( Bad Request) to the android app

Comment: What does the string contain? I asked that too. Why aren't you answering?

Comment: public void _postfile()
    {
        byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("1.mp3"));
        string orderid = "50";
        string mobilenumber = "9810098100";
        string fileformat = ".mp3";
        string status = "Call not picked";
        string serviceResponse =  PostAudio(bytes, orderid, mobilenumber, fileformat, status); //post file and get xml response from service
        Response.Write(serviceResponse); //print xml response on webpage
    }

Comment: ????? I asked for the content of String serviceUrl. Not of those other stings.

Comment: serviceUrl =  "https://www.capricorn.cash/getway.svc/uploadaudio/?token=" + _servicetoken + "&orderid=" + orderid + "&mobilenumber=" + mobilenumber + "&fileformat=" + fileformat +  "&status=" + status;

Comment: The comment above is what I used in Service URL - the values are mentioned in my previous post

Comment: This is what I did in C# string serviceUrl = string.Format(_serviceaudiourl, _servicetoken, orderid, mobilenumber, fileformat, status);                                                                       _serviceaudiourl and _servicetoken is mentioned in the same function while the other parameters are being sent from the other function

Comment: Yes i saw that. That's why i asked what the resulting string was. For the third time: what is the content of String serviceUrl after that statement. Rephrased: what is the resulting url?

Comment: https://www.capricorn.cash/getway.svc/uploadaudio/?token=DD9BBF0C749261F3A3F5D9AE62CFE29E&orderid=50&mobilenumber=9810098100&fileformat=.mp3&status=No_Anwer

Comment: Please remove the first h. As you see it's unreadabls now as the forum software shows it as a link. Or place it between layout ticks.

Comment: This is the content - zttps://www.capricorn.cash/getway.svc/uploadaudio/?token=DD9BBF0C749261F3A3F5D9AE62CFE29E&orderid=50&mobilenumber=9810098100&fileformat=.mp3&status=No_Anwer

Comment: I do not understand too much of that C# code. But it looks like a combined GET and POST request as all key=value pairs go into the url and only the file content is posted. And that is how you did it in your Android code too. Now i can imagine that the server wants to have all parameters POSTed. I cannot see if that C# class is doing that. But i can imagine that it does. So take the params from the url and post all key=value pairs too. Just try it.

Comment: You have no access to the server code? Would make things easy.

Comment: 'string serviceUrl = string.Format(_serviceau.....'. I asked for the contents of this C# string. Did you give that? It looks as if you finally gave the content of the android String.

Comment: The resultant string is the same ...it cannot be different